# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, caching

I am trying to insert the data into database using JPA.Now,When i try to insert the data using API,then following error is showing:

```
Info:   em:::::com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper@3f8f5f5f
Warning:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.
Error Code: 20000
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
```

My codes look like this:

UserDAOImpl.java

```
 package com.ashwin.cacheapp.dao.impl;
    import com.ashwin.cacheapp.dao.UserDAO;
    import com.ashwin.cacheapp.model.User;
    import com.ashwin.cacheapp.util.HibernateConnector;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;

    @Stateless
    public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UserPA")
    private  EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void insertUser(User user) {
      System.out.println("em:::::" + em);
      em.persist(user);

    }
     }
```

User.java.I have also declared @Id for the sequence generator.But the error is coming related to sequence generator.

```
package com.ashwin.cacheapp.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.QueryHint;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Data
@Cacheable(true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "User")
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERINFO")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "select u from User u ", hints = {
@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}),
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findById", query = "select u from User u where u.id = :id")
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
@Column(name = "USER_NAME")
private String userName;
@Column(name = "USER_ADDRESS")
private String userAddress;

public User() {
}

public User(long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public User(String userName, String userAddress) {
this.userName = userName;
this.userAddress = userAddress;
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
    <artifactId>CacheApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>CacheApp</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>  
        <repository>
    <id>jfrog-libs</id>
    <name>jfrog-libs</name>
    <url>http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jcs-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcs/jcs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jcs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/concurrent/concurrent -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
      <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> 
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId> 
    <version>16.0</version> 
</dependency>

   <!--added dependency-->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate EHCache API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- EHCache uses slf4j for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                <version>3.2-b06</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
                </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>

      </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="UserPA" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <!-- database connection -->
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>


            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/ehcache.xml"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am trying to save the data but the error hits at em.persist(user).My persistence.xml file is inside META_INF folder.

Comment: You use `GenerationType.AUTO` while its obvious that you have `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` requires additional configuration

Comment: can u help me whats worng in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are using MySQL database. There you usually have an auto_increment on the primary key columns.

Therefore you should use IDENTITY as strategy:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
```

Additionally I can see that you are using GlassFish and EclipseLink but you have Hibernate properties set in the persistence.xml.

That will not work. You have to clean up the persistence.xml first.

Comment: yes my persistence.xml is not working.what is the problem? its not creating tables automatically.Please can u help me the solution

Comment: I don't understand why you have Hibernate configuration in the persistence.xml but use EclipseLink